# How to use Join as a Select column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT X.ID, X.NAME, CASE R.ID WHEN NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ISRELATED
FROM TABLE X
INNER JOIN RELATIVE R ON R.NAMEID = X.ID
```

I'm trying to get results look like this structure, and not pull any duplicate rows from table X:

```
ID
NAME
ISRELATED (boolean)
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Well i changed the case statement in this example to help illustrate the need better, but currently returning duplicates with all the same value for the related column, like all ones or zeros

Comment: just add `DISTINCT` to your statement

Comment: I don't know how to do the CASE statement for this and which type of JOIN to use.  WHEN IS NOT NULL doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using INNER JOIN will return only those rows from X which have a corresponding row in R. Use Left outer join instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.ID, X.NAME, CASE WHEN R.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ISRELATED 
FROM TABLE X 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RELATIVE R ON R.NAMEID = X.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.ID, X.NAME, CASE WHEN R.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ISRELATED 
FROM TABLE X 
INNER JOIN RELATIVE R ON R.NAMEID = X.ID
```

Comment: that returns all 1's for ISRELATED and doesn't show the 0 ones.

Comment: maybe you need to explain what exactly you are expecting, but my guess is since you are using `INNER` join it will only return the ones with existing records in the `RELATIVE` table, might want to try `LEFT OUTER` join

Answer (score 0):

I think that you has an error in `CASE` and have to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    X.ID, 
    X.NAME, 
    CASE WHEN R.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ISRELATED 
FROM TABLE X 
LEFT JOIN RELATIVE R ON R.NAMEID = X.ID
```